# How to delete in vim everything in between the cursor and the end of the line while on insert mode?

Tags: vim

While in normal mode I can delete all the characters after the cursor by typing `d$`. I'd like to achieve the same but in ***insert mode*** in the same way that you can delete things to the left of the cursor with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many ways:

- <kbd>esc</kbd>, <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
- <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>end</kbd>, <kbd>del</kbd>
- <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>end</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd>

Don't be afraid of falling back to the normal mode even for a short instant.

Comment: The first two worked perfectly, however, I had problems with the third one. Does S mean Shift? ; Shift-end <del> and Shift-end + s did not work?

Comment: `<C-o>D` -- new to me. Awesome!

Comment: Indeed, `S` stands for shift.
I guess you are using plain vim under console. gvim has a better support of the keyboard that the one the default configuration of all consoles offers to vim.

Comment: @LucHermitte That last one doesn't work in vim or in gvim.  It works in notepad.

Comment: Oh. My mistake, sorry. I forgot I have a mapping to `<C-\><C-N>v<End>` for `<S-End>`. NB: this is buggy, and should use `<c-o>v<end>` instead.

Comment: +1 Do not fear normal mode.. This is *the* essential feature of Vim in my opinion.